# Kendo Grid with Ajax model id issue

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Consider [this example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html).

If you use this example (on your code in debug mode) you'll see that after you add a second object and press the update button,  two requests will be sent to the server (this is why two objects exists with the same id).
I am looking for assistance on a methodology to avoid this (generatedynamic id)?

Could anyone assist me with code or information to meet my needs?

Comment: I only see one post to the server for each add.  And they came back with unique ProductID values.  What made you think their IDs were duplicated?  Perhaps did you double click on the 'Update' button?

Comment: +1 @NickDeVore (I only see one post and IDs use to be assigned by the server). If anyhow you want to generate unique ids on the client, you might use `kendo.guid()`.

Comment: Here is my problem described.Thanks,Guys. http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting